# Concat/Concatenate Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

All, I come before you with a puzzle that I cannot figure out.

I recently transitioned to Office 365 from 2010 and am having a world of difficulty adapting my formulas and scripts to work in the new platform.

Particularly, I am running into an issue where one of my `SUM(IF(CONCATENATE` formulas can no longer find data.

Previously, in 2010, I had a formula as follows:

```
{=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(B8,C8,D8)=CONCATENATE(ProjectData!A2:A20000,ProjectData!C2:C20000,ProjectData!W2:W20000),ProjectData!T2:T20000))}
```

This formula would sum a range of numbers if 3 cells matched 3 cells in a range of data.

This no longer works in Office 2016.

Has any syntax changed that might be causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SUMIFS() would be better regardless of version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(ProjectData!T:T,ProjectData!A:A,B8,ProjectData!C:C,C8,ProjectData!W:W,D8)
```

Comment: Scott, this formula fixed my problem after I changed a few of the cell references. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Is there a reason why Excel 2016 isn't backwards compatible with formulas written in 2010?

Comment: That formula should work in 2016, if you had to change the references in my formula then your references are off in yours.